# In Typescript, extending Array results in an Array type, how can I get it to return List type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

if I do the following:

```
export class List<T> extends Array<T> {
    public constructor() { super(); };
}

var listtype : List = new List<String>();
```

Then the compiled javascript generates the following:

```
var List = (function (_super) {
    __extends(List, _super);
    function List() {
        var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
        return _this;
     }
}
```

If I look at listtype.**proto** in the watch window, it's an Array, not a List.

How do I get a List type out of this code when transpiling with Typescript so that I can access other methods of list (which exist in my solution)?

Cheers,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

I was being an idiot - it turns out that my project was set up to build ES3 code, setting the target to ES6 makes these types come out right.